# Selecting ID's based on multiple subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

This my my first post to Stack Overflow, I appreciate and will take in any positive criticism to better form any future questions.

Question:
I'm trying to create a Select query where to gather all orders which have only the top 8 items in them.

I'm working with MS-Access 2013.

My current Query, which doesn't work, looks like this.

```
SELECT OrderID
From DirectOrders
WHERE OrderID <> ANY
(
    SELECT OrderID
    FROM DirectOrders
    WHERE SKU <> ANY
    (
        SELECT TOP 8 SKU
        FROM DirectOrders
        GROUP BY  SKU
        ORDER BY COUNT(SKU) DESC
    )
)
```

The single table that is below.

```
OrderID Customer    SKU Qty
177622  CustomerA   1001    20
177622  CustomerA   1002    2
177624  CustomerB   1001    200
177626  CustomerC   1003    50
177626  CustomerC   1004    150
177630  CustomerC   1005    1000
177632  CustomerA   1006    1
177632  CustomerA   1007    3
177632  CustomerA   1008    9
177632  CustomerA   1009    1
177632  CustomerA   1010    4
177632  CustomerA   1011    3
177634  CustomerC   1012    5
177634  CustomerC   1013    5
177640  CustomerD   1014    4
177642  CustomerA   1015    4
177642  CustomerA   1016    48
177642  CustomerA   1017    15
177644  CustomerB   1018    50
```

Here was the flow that I was trying to accomplish.

1. Select Top 8 SKU's by Count
2. Select All OrderID's that do not have one of those 8 SKU's
3. Select All OrderID's That are not part of the selected OrderID's in List 2.

Comment: *Select Top 8 SKU's by Count...* what count?

Comment: select top 8 FROM DirectOrders order by qty? I think that would get your step 1.

Comment: It would be the count of SKU, since it's sample data the result will look strange. The SKU will repeat hundreds of times.

Comment: Would it be count of SKU or sum of Qty?

Comment: is there really only one table for all of this?

Comment: Yes, just a single table.

Comment: Count of SKU @Kateract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with aggregation:

```
SELECT do.OrderID
FROM DirectOrders as do LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT TOP 8 SKU
      FROM DirectOrders
      GROUP BY SKU
      ORDER BY COUNT(SKU) DESC, SKU
     ) as s8
     ON do.SKU = s8.SKU
GROUP BY do.OrderId
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(s8.SKU);
```

Notes:

- In MS Access, `TOP` is really `TOP WITH TIES`.  To get *exactly* 8 values you need a tie breaker.  This query uses `SKU` for that purpose.
- The `LEFT JOIN` determines if there is a match between each item in an order and the top 8 items.
- The `HAVING` clause is saying:  The count of rows with items is the same as the count of rows that match one of the top 8.  Hence, all are in the order.

Comment: This is definitely a more elegant solution then mine, however I would also add the same caveat that I did in my answer and say that you may want to add order by clauses in addition to `SKU` to make the top 8 that you get more relevant than arbitrary sku numbers, such as `SUM(QTY)` for total quantity or `MAX(ORDERID)` for latest orders.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for the clear answer.  I appreciate all the help i received on this.  If i wanted to select the entire column's, would you recommend i do the following? I will specify each column, however for the mean time i will run with the asterisk.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM DirectOrders
WHERE OrderID = ANY
(
SELECT do.OrderID
FROM DirectOrders as do LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT TOP 8 SKU
      FROM DirectOrders
      GROUP BY SKU
      ORDER BY COUNT(SKU) DESC, SUM(QTY) DESC, MAX(ORDERID) DESC, SKU
     ) as s8
     ON do.SKU = s8.SKU
GROUP BY do.OrderId
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(s8.SKU)
);

Comment: Thank you @Kateract I will add those as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this. However, you might get some strange results if you are using count SKU because apart from 1001 the count of the other SKUs is 1. So apart from 1001, all the other SKUs are in the top 8 based on the count(SKU)

SELECT * FROM DirectOrderswhere SKU in
(select top 8 SKU from DirectOrders group by SKU order by count(SKU) desc);

Comment: I'm looking to not include orders with SKU's that are not part of the TOP 8.  The end result would display only entire orders (OrderID), where TOP 8 is present.

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for.  However I would like to show only the TOP 8 opposed to calling the bottom 99 percent.

SELECT *
FROM DirectOrders
WHERE OrderID <>ALL
(
SELECT OrderID
FROM DirectOrders
WHERE SKU IN
(SELECT TOP 99 PERCENT SKU
FROM DirectOrders
GROUP BY SKU
ORDER BY COUNT(SKU) ASC));

Answer (score 0):

Access's TOP function does not break ties, so instead of reporting just the top 8, it will order the items per your order by and then report enough to cover the top value you put in, and all ties.  For example, with your sample data, it will report the same 17 records if you do top 8 or just top 2, since all but one of your `SKU`s have only 1 order.

If you want to report only the top 8, you should add to the query to make the ordering unique. In this case, I would probably order by `COUNT(SKU) DESC, COUNT(QTY) DESC, MAX(ORDERID) desc, SKU`  So that it prioritizes highest number of orders, highest quantity, and then makes a choice based on the latest `OrderID` with that sku, and if all else fails, order by the `SKU` itself.  Only the `SKU` is guaranteed to be unique for each row, but just ordering by `SKU` might not give the best result if you are looking for the truly relevant "top 8".

```
SELECT OrderID
From DirectOrders
WHERE OrderID NOT IN
(
    SELECT OrderID
    FROM DirectOrders
    WHERE SKU NOT IN
    (
        SELECT TOP 8 SKU
        FROM DirectOrders
        GROUP BY  SKU
        ORDER BY COUNT(SKU) DESC, SUM(QTY) DESC, MAX(ORDERID) DESC, SKU
    )
)
```

Comment: How would I only show the OrderID's that have only a TOP 8 SKU? Opposed to one's that may have a TOP 8 as well as another SKU out of the TOP 8.

Comment: Sorry, I tested using `NOT IN` instead of `<> ANY` and they are not equivalent.  Updated my answer.